# connecting an action of button in view in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I am beginner in asp.net mvc . I am going to connect an action of button in view.
but i cant. i work with web form, in fact i want to click on the button, create action will be called and insert the data.
my code is as following:

The Controller:

```
namespace BookStore.Controllers
{
    public class BookController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(book bookobj)
        {
            var dBook=new DBook();
            dBook.Insertbook(bookobj);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@model BookStore.Models.DomainObject.book

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>insert data/h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

    <fieldset>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model=> model.book_name)
        </div>    
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.book_name)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.book_qty)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.book_qty)
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <input id="Button_craete_book" type="button" value="insert" />
        </div>       
    </fieldset>    
}
```

Comment: you have a error in you view the <h2>insert data</h2> is missing the < on the closing tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the button type to "submit":

`<input id="Button_craete_book" type="submit" value="insert" />`

That will post the form and values to the Edit method in the controller, as marked with the HttpPost attribute.